# Questions regarding Objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I'm using Code Academy to learn basic javascript. I had a problem when dealing in assigning objects with const.

The tutorial says:
It’s important to know that although we can’t reassign an object declared with const, we can still mutate it, meaning we can add new properties and change the properties that are there.

```
const spaceship = {type: 'shuttle'};
spaceship = {type: 'alien'}; // TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
spaceship.type = 'alien'; // Changes the value of the type property
spaceship.speed = 'Mach 5'; // Creates a new key of 'speed' with a value of 'Mach 5'
```

Why I can't change the value of the type property with the code in line 2??

My guess on this: Since we couldn't reassign any value declared by const, we still can change the value of type property using bracket notation or dot notation. Is it right??

Thanks

Comment: You are correct. You cannot reassign the value of an object declared with `const`. You can use dot notation or bracket notation… `spaceship['type'] = 'alien';` to change properties on the object.

Comment: In JS `{}` creates in new object. So in line 2 you are creating new object and assigning it to constant `spaceship`, which is not allowed.